# How to get the group of qubits which are on the same port of measurement?

Tags: measurement, ibm-quantum-devices

From IBMQ's quantum computer, we know that logical qubits are mapped to their computers' physical qubits, and then they are measured to get classical bits (0 and 1). For instance, a 27-qubit ibmq_kolkata computer's topology looks like this:
[image: ibmq_kolkata's qubit topology]

---

In fact all other 27 qubit quantum computers share the same topology, and as we measure a circuit, the signal line actually measures from 0,6,9,17,20,26 these qubits.
My question is, is there a function or a paper that mentioned which qubits are paired with the qubit that is measured? I remember IBM released a short article about it but I can't find it. From now I can only be sure that qubit 1 is definitely measured with qubit 0 (same for 6 and 7 and others), since qubit 1's closet measure port is qubit 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, the Falcon (27/28-qubit) devices have multiplexed readout since revision 4 (see https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services/resources/docs/runtime/manage/systems/processors). While currently there does not seem to be a way to extract the multiplexed channels (the logical measurement channels corresponding to a physical channel or "port") from the backend details, Fig. 1b of this paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/2008.08571) shows which qubits are multiplexed to each readout. While this shows the multiplexed qubits tend to be close to each other (and different in frequency!), this may vary for difference revisions and device families.